# Need help, VBA, Stoping a private sub event from another private sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have private sub textbox1_keydown and private sub textbox1_afterupdate. If im finish filling up textbox1 then clicking the combobox still populates it with lists. But when im finish filling up textbox1 then pressing the enter key the combobox populates a abnormal lists. cmbo4 is a sub event where it populates the combobox based on what i input in the textbox1. My codes in on a userform

Heres my code:

```
Private sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As_ 
MSForms.ReturnInteger,ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode=13 Then
ComboBox4.Clear
Call cmbo4
ComboBox4.DropDown
ComboBox4.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

Now i have this textbox1_afterupdate event, im adding this event to avoid errors to my program when the user wants to use the mouse to click the next combobox and not by pressing enter.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
ComboBox4.Clear
Call cmbo4
ComboBox4.DropDown
ComboBox4.SetFocus
End Sub
```

My problem is to stop the event textbox1_afterupdate to perform when the user press the enter key so that my combobox wont have abnormal lists

Comment: Why don't you use the Exit Event instead of KeyDown and Afterupdate?

Comment: I tried it but combobox4.clear, combobox4.dropdown and combobox.setfocus wont effect..only the cmbo4 sub event runs

Comment: You could Add the combobox4.dropdown and combobox.setfocus in your cmbo4 (public in a module) and call it with application.ontime

Answer (score 0):

```
Option explicit
Dim InProgress as boolean  'module level variable

Private sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger,ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode=13 Then
     ComboBox4.Clear
     Call cmbo4
     ComboBox4.DropDown
     ComboBox4.SetFocus
     InProgess = true
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_AfterUpdate()
if inProgress then  'we just updated it so don't repeat
     inprogress = False  'just clear the event
else
     ComboBox4.Clear
     Call cmbo4
     ComboBox4.DropDown
     ComboBox4.SetFocus
     inprogress = False 'and clear the event
End IF
End Sub
```

Comment: IMO it's better to have only the calling routine set the control variable value; other routines should only check its value. That way you can use it to stop multiple other events.

Comment: Rory - if you don't clear it then, once you've used the keyboard once, you can't ever use the mouse because the variable never clears.

Comment: Apologies - didn't pay attention to what the events actually were in this case!

Comment: Although, given the explicit setfocus which will trigger the afterupdate, you should still be able to reset it in the keydown event.